# Activerecord::Relation: getting fields from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get an understanding about the inner features of Active Record playing with IRB.

I have a small database with a few tables which I created using SQL. Then I connected Active Record to that database using a Ruby script. I already loaded the models, which are classes with the tables' names singularized, and made all attributes accessible via `attr_accessor` but I only get the id and the rest return nil when trying to get them. Any clue?

I have the table "empresas" with four records and the class Empresa:

```
2.2.1 :001 > load 'config.db'
 => true 
2.2.1 :002 > e = Empresa.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Empresa id: 1, razon_social: "Holbrook Co.", cuit: "33-22564787-4", domicilio: "San Lorenzo 336", localidad_id: 7>, #<Empresa id: 2, razon_social: "Marshfield Llc.", cuit: "30-13547542-0", domicilio: "Av. de Mayo 110", localidad_id: 2>, #<Empresa id: 3, razon_social: "Iron Cobra Inc.", cuit: "30-24652120-8", domicilio: "9 de Julio 332", localidad_id: 20>, #<Empresa id: 4, razon_social: "Apple Inc.", cuit: "30-43753246-4", domicilio: "Riverside Road 342", localidad_id: 4>]> 
2.2.1 :003 > e[2]
 => #<Empresa id: 3, razon_social: "Iron Cobra Inc.", cuit: "30-24652120-8", domicilio: "9 de Julio 332", localidad_id: 20> 
2.2.1 :004 > e[2].id
 => 3 
2.2.1 :005 > e[2].razon_social
 => nil 
2.2.1 :006 > e[2].cuit
 => nil
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :localidad
  attr_accessor :razon_social, :cuit, :domicilio, :localidad_id
end
```

This model is required in the script that makes the connection to the database, along with `active_record` and `fb` (I'm using firebird for the database).

Comment: What do you have in your model?

Comment: I am hoping that your model looks like `class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base  end`

Comment: class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :localidad
  attr_accessor :razon_social, :cuit, :domicilio, :localidad_id
end

Comment: Add it to your question, with proper formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord will *automatically* create accessors for columns in your database tables.

When you define accessors with `attr_accessor`, you override those accessors.

Try removing that call to `attr_accessor`, then your calls should go on to the database values!

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear it, don't forget to click the check-mark on on this answer if it solved your problem!

Enjoy learning ActiveRecord :)

Comment: there u have it.. (this was my 1st question as u can immagine), thanks again